Epsilon-Delta Proof when the function is a constant and the limit equals the constant
$\lim_{x\to a} c=c$
Proof:
Given $\epsilon>0$ and let us find a number, $\delta>0$, such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta$ then $|c-c|<\epsilon$. But $|c-c|=0$
I got this far, and the answer from the book for the rest of the proof is:
But $|c-c|=0$, so this will be true no matter what $\delta$ we pick.
I am not understanding. If $|c-c|=0$ and $|c-c|<\epsilon$, but we are saying that "Given $\epsilon>0$" how can this be a proof that c is the limit? I tried to draw a diagram but still not intuitively understanding how this proof finishes and lets us pick any $\delta$.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $f$ is constant, $f(x) = f(a)$ for all $x$, so for any interval centered around $a$, we'll satisfy $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$ for all $x$ in that interval. Thus, there is not only at least one $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$ for $x \in (a - \delta, a + \delta)$; every $\delta > 0$ works.

@user1090793 thank you as well, both are bringing clarity.

Make sure that you understood the definition well. When you are given $\epsilon >0$ you want to find a $\delta >0$ such that when $|x-c|<\delta$ you will have $|c-c|<\epsilon.$ But the last statement is equivalent to saying that $0<\epsilon$ which is already the case from the beginning independent of the choice of $\delta$.

Thank you, I think having a little break help reset my brain. I was not seeing that $0<\epsilon$ was the same thing as $\epsilon>0$. I am going to continue to work on the definition.
